# Convert String to Byte

Tags: scala

I need to convert a Char to an Byte. I belief this should be very simple but i don't find a nice solution.

```
0x7A.toChar => 'z'
'z'.???? => 0x7A
```

Edit:

I'm to tired...
'z'.toByte => 0x7A

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
scala> 'z'.toByte
res0: Byte = 122

scala> res0.toChar
res1: Char = z
```

Note that a `Char` in Scala (and Java) is Unicode UTF-16 which means that it is 2 bytes. You might lose information!

Comment: Ah that's the difference between Byte and Char ;)
(I have to communicate with an old system => so i need 8-Bit Char...)